# NullReferenceExpection in a Integration test project for an asp.net nhibernate solution

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have  a .NET 3.5 solution with an asp.net(web site) project with fluentnhibernate and it's test project(class library project).i've referenced the asp.net project in the test project and with all fluentnhibernate/nhibenate dlls.

What i fail to comprehend is that, on a run of a webform (hit from browser) let's say Test.aspx, building of schema is successfull and i could see the tables in my database.
here is the method i call on Test.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISession session = SessionManager.Instance.OpenSession();
       SessionManager.BuildSchema(session);
    }
}
```

i happen to use the same method in CanGenerateSchema method of my test class and it always fails

```
 [TestFixture]
public class CanGenerateSchemaTestSuite
{
    [Test]
    public void CanGenarateSchema()
    {
        ISession session = SessionManager.Instance.OpenSession();
        SessionManager.BuildSchema(session);
    }
}
```

here is the SessionManager i use :

```
public sealed class SessionManager
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;


    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return Instance._sessionFactory; }
    }


    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return _sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionManager Instance
    {
        get { return NestedSessionManager._sessionManager; }
    }

    public ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return Instance.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
    }


    private static Configuration SaveConfigs;

    private SessionManager()
    {
        try
        {

            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
            //from the debugging the code breaks from here when trying to get connectionstring.
                string constring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localdb"].ToString();
                FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(
                        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(constring))
                    .Mappings(m =>
                    {
                        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<myproject.model.Request>();
                        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<myproject.model.Route>();
                    })
                    .ExposeConfiguration((x) =>
                    {
                        SaveConfigs = x;
                        x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread_static");

                    });
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);

        }

    }


    public static void BuildSchema(ISession session)
    {
        var export = new SchemaExport(SaveConfigs);
        export.Execute(false,true,false,session.Connection,null);
    }

    class NestedSessionManager
    {
        internal static readonly SessionManager _sessionManager = new SessionManager();
    }
}
```

So from my comment the NullReferenceException happens when accessing the connectionstring. I don't have the explanation on why that happens.I'm sure it's some kind of gotchas, i can't get over it.I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a hand here.thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localdb"]` from Test.aspx would be pulling from your `web.config` file on a web project.

That file wouldn't be accessible to your test project (I'm assuming your tests are in a separate project from your web site). You should be able to get around this by adding an `app.config` file into your test project with the correct localdb settings or rather than using a configuration string, use FluentNHibernate's fluent builder.

Example app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="localdb" value="yourconnectionstring" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks.i thought about that and it seems to me that it will be redundant having another connectionstring in the test project.It works now. but is that a good practice? just a question

Comment: It depends on how often it changes.  If you haven't, maybe give some thought to the Fluent Builders, then your code is compiled and in one place. http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localdb"]` is `null` then the `.ToString()` call will cause the `NullReferenceException`.

Ensure the "localdb" setting exists.